Do I have to pay twice for network fee?
I'm very new in crypto world and right now I'm trying to swap this coin but as you can see in the screenshot the ETH gas fee (Uniswap) is only $15 but once I tried to confirm transaction at my wallet it says the fee is over $38. Which one do I actually pay? Do both add up cause goddamn that's crazy expensive compared to any other network.


There are two transactions:

Approval Transaction: The first transaction approves the token you're swapping from.  This allows Uniswap's smart contract to transfer tokens on your behalf.  This is a one-time process unless you change the amount you want to swap or switch to a different token.
Swap Transaction: The second transaction is the actual swap transaction where the tokens are exchanged.  Once you've approved the token transfer, you can proceed with the swap.  This transaction executes Uniswap's smart contract to exchange the approved tokens at the current market rate.


So I gonna have to pay both of those fees right?

Yes.  From the screenshot it looks like you've already paid for the first one (the red button has changed from Approve to Swap).

No. You only pay a single fee. Both Uniswap and Metamask are showing an approximation. Likely they are using different gas price providers so the calculated fee are different.
The transaction fee has two components:

base fee: depends on the network congestion will be burn.
priority fee: the fee paid to the block builder.

The base fee varies from block to block so the estimation might change accordingly.
A higher priority fee should make the transaction to be confirmed faster.
Metamask default configuration is to confirm transactions quickly so it will use a higher gas price. In Metamask advanced section you should be able to change the configuration to lower the gas price. Just be aware that if it is too low your transaction may get stuck indefinitely.
